# mac os ping: ping must run as root

Tags: macos, root, ping

in the **mac os 10.13.6** iterm3 terminal

```
➜ ping baidu.com 
ping: ping must run as root
```

but when:

```
➜ sudo ping baidu.com   
PING baidu.com (220.181.57.216): 48 data bytes   
56 bytes from 220.181.57.216: icmp_seq=0 ttl=54 time=59.912 ms   
56 bytes from 220.181.57.216: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=48.389 ms
```

it's ok.

How can I make the ping normal?

Answer (score 3):

it works!

```
➜ sudo chown root /usr/local/bin/ping
➜ sudo chmod +s /usr/local/bin/ping
➜ ping baidu.com
```

Answer (score 0):

add to your zshrc

```
 export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

Comment: Please help likaiguo.happy and future readers by explaining why this solves the question.